# Cut div in half horizontally

Tags: html, css

How do I change the CSS [here](http://www.oddskill.net/test/csstest) to work with dynamic parent div sizes and continue to populate half the height and complete width of the parent div `theapp`? Specifically, `#innerpanelA` and `#innerpanelB`

I tried using % values instead of the fixed sizes but that failed horribly.
A pure css and html solution would be best, no js no resizing.

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest the two child divs (`#innerpanelA` and `#innerpanelB`) inside of the parent div (`theapp`) and then add the below code to your CSS:

```
#innerpanelA {top:0; height:50%;}
#innerpanelB {top:50%; height:50%;}
```

The `top:0` element will tell `#innerpanelA` to sit exactly at the top of the parent div and take up half of the space (`height:50%`) no matter what the size of the div is.

The `top:50%` element will tell `#innerpanelB` to sit exactly half way down the div and take up the bottom half of the space (`height:50%`) no matter what the size of the div is.

Both child divs height will add up to 100% and will be responsive to the browser size, zoom, etc. since the `%` is used.

Comment: Be sure to upvote and accept the answer to show others as correct.

Answer (score 0):

give chessclockpanel height:100% and innerpanelA and innerpanelB height:50% each.

Comment: This does not work and looks then like [link](http://www.oddskill.net/test/csstest1)

Comment: you haven' t given chessclockpanel height:100%